# Adding several schema encoding URLs in Django REST framework swagger-ui.html template

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi, drf-spectacular

I have the `swagger-ui.html` file in a Django (v4.1.2) app as follow (taken from the [Django REST framework doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Swagger</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "{% url 'yaml-schema' %}",
        url: "{% url 'json-schema' %}",<!-- This is what I naturally want to add -->
          dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
          presets: [
              SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
              SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
          ],
          layout: "BaseLayout",
          requestInterceptor: (request) => {
              request.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = "{{ csrf_token }}"
              return request;
          }
      })
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I have defined two paths defining the schema in the urlpatterns list in my main `url.py`, one for a YAML encoded version and the other for a JSON encoded version of the schema:

```py
(...)
from drf_spectacular.views import (
    SpectacularYAMLAPIView,
    SpectacularJSONAPIView,
    SpectacularSwaggerView,
)

(...)

# OAPI 3
urlpatterns =  [
    ...
    path(
        rf"{API_BASE}schema/yaml/",
        SpectacularYAMLAPIView.as_view(),
        name="yaml-schema",
    ),
    path(
        rf"{API_BASE}schema/json/",
        SpectacularJSONAPIView.as_view(),
        name="json-schema",
    ),
    path(
        rf"{API_BASE}docs/",
        SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(
            template_name="swagger-ui.html",
            url_name="yaml-schema"
        ),
        name="swagger-ui",
    ),
]
```

drf_spectacular.views doc: https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html#module-drf_spectacular.views

I would like to add two links on top of the swagger API doc page, one per schema encoding:

[image]

But when I add the line `url: "{% url 'json-schema' %}",` in the `swagger-ui.html` file, there is only the last one, e.g. the JSON link on my API documentation page and I cannot figure out what is this `const ui = SwaggerUIBundle()` and where it comes from.

And there doesn't seem to be a way to pass a list of URL in the `url_name` parameters of the [drf_spectacular.views.SpectacularSwaggerView](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html#drf_spectacular.views.SpectacularSwaggerView).

Do you know how I could tweak the small paragraph on the of the swagger page in order to customize it?
In the current case, by simply adding by another link to the JSON formatted API schema.

Comment: I looked at doing this kind of thing as well, but there isn't really a way.  SwaggerUI is a bunch of `js` and resources loaded from a CDN, and it only supports that one URL.  You can check out https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/installation/ and perhaps fork the repo & customize it.  I know I'd like something a bit more customizable too!

Comment: Also, you can maybe see about writing a custom component to modify rendering, without replacing all the package: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/customization/overview.md

Comment: @Andrew please refer to my answer. swagger-ui does support this with `urls`: https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/ This can be simply set the python settings. No need for forking/template hacking or other trickery.

Answer (score 1):

by adding another `url` entry to a "js dict" you essentially override the first entry. "Last one counts" does apply to both js and python wrt dictionaries/objects. That is simply how the languages work.

What you can do is use the *swagger-ui topbar* feature as a selector. Notice the `urls` list instead of an `url`.

Also notice that this is the `settings.py` snippet. No need for a custom template. This can all be achieved from the settings.

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    "SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA": False,
    "SWAGGER_UI_SETTINGS": '''{
        deepLinking: true,
        urls: [{url: "/en/api/v1/schema/yaml", name: "yaml"}, {url: "/en/api/v1/schema/json", name: "json"}],
        presets: [SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis, SwaggerUIStandalonePreset],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout",
    }''',
}
```

I don't really understand the reason for this though. Content-wise both are identical, i.e. they contain exactly the same information just with a different encoding. And swagger-ui does translate one representation into the other internally anyway.